# Get Data(data,columns number,row number) from a changed row on Handsontable

Tags: angular, typescript, handsontable

I have a handsontable in a Angular Application, I have multiple columns but in 3 columns I need do a specific action.

Column A - Have a dropdown with some values

Column B - Have a dropdown with some values

Column C - Will change if A or B have select one value from the dropdown.

The table is dynamic and the columns too, so sometimes the columns A,B and C doesn't exist.

My question is:

The handsontable have any options to get row, column and data from a cell changed?

I need to pass the data for the http request and for set the new data for C column.

Answer (score 1):

There are hooks like beforeChange and afterChange which could be used for capturing any changes in the cells, refer https://handsontable.com/docs/7.2.2/Hooks.html. The value for the column C could be set based upon changes in columns A or B with the help of the above and you can build the request object and resolve it upon any event as per the requirements of your application.